# Python not finding module even after installing with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I'm using python 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 18.04.3.
I have a folder set up as follows:

```
.
└── my_package
    ├── independent_modules1
    ├── independent_modules2
    ├── setup.py
    └── src
        ├── sub_package1
        ├── module1
        └── module2
```

my_package is a git repository, and is why the independent_modules are put along.

/src is where all the modules for "my_package" are.

setup.py has the following content:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
      name="my_package",
      version="1.0",
      package_dir={'': 'src'},
      packages=find_packages(where='src')
)
```

I created a virtual environment, called my_env, to be used with the project.

While inside the virtual environment, and with all the packages required already installed, I tried to install my own package by doing the following:

```
 (my_env) my_user: ~/folder/my_package$ pip3 install -e .
```

Pip says the package was installed successfully, and it lists my_package if I run pip3 list.

But if I run python3 and attempt to import my_package I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'.

What seems to be the problem?

I had attempted this before, but without the src folder setup (the modules for my_package were all under my_package, alongside setup.py) and it had worked.

Comment: Have you installed it through the terminal? If so check which Python you used to install it. Ubuntu comes with Python2.7 as default if I remember correctly. Once you have installed Python3 you can `rm` Python2.7. I have had this problem with other modules before and this solved it for me

Comment: What is put under `name` arg in your setup script is your distribution name, it is used in order to install your project. It is not importable. What's importable is the contents of the `packages` list. In your example, `my_package` is used to _install_ the project, e.g. via `pip install my_package`, while you should be able to _import_ `sub_package1`, `module1`, `module2` etc.

Comment: @hoefling Put your comment as an answer, I was able to solve with your help.
I put `sub_package1`, `module1` and `module2` in a `my_package` folder under `src` and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting the machine. It worked for me.